# using jQuery handle stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My script follow like this

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.customize_box = function() {
   //get the element id from the handle
   var my_id = this.attr('id');
   //add some layout elements before to this input box
   $('<p>hello</p>').before('#' + my_id);
      alert(my_id);
   }; 

   })( jQuery );
```

This is my jquery function coded to add some html elements at before and after to the fired element.

```
$('#tags').customize_box();
```

This is the firing code, im firing it for an input field with id "tags"
My HTML is like here

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="tags" size="50"  value="sankar is playing"/>
</div>
```

The problem is, in the function, Im getting the fired element properties including ID, and im saving the id into a variable, but im unable to write some html using .before() as you see in the code, alert is coming up correctly, but HELLO is not adding to the content, can some one please assist me in debugging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `insertBefore`, not `before`. Secondly, you can get the instance of the element the plugin is instanciated on using `this`, so you don't need to concatenate together a selector. Try this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customize_box = function () {
        var my_id = this.attr('id');

        $('<p>hello</p>').insertBefore(this);
        alert(my_id);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWcWV/)

Comment: and can you tell me is there any function to add some elements after to the fired element?

Comment: Yes, you can use `insertAfter()`

Comment: Im sorry//add some layout elements before to this input box
   $('<div class="before">').insertBefore(this);
   //add terminating layout elements
   $('its end</div>').insertAfter(this);
      alert(my_id);..this is not working, not even alert is raising, can you help in this too?

Comment: You can't add part of an element like that - you have to insert whole elements. If you want to surround another element you need to use `wrap()`: `$(this).wrap('<div />');`

Answer (score 0):

May be some off, but I think it is a good idea to handle all selected elements in your function:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customize_box = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
        //get the element id from the handle
        var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
        //add some layout elements before to this input box
        $('<p>' + my_id+ '</p>').insertBefore(this);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thus you can call it for multiple inputs:

```
$('input').customize_box();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="tags" size="50" value="sankar is playing" />
    <input id="tags1" size="50" value="sankar is playing" />
    <input id="tags2" size="50" value="sankar is playing" />
</div>
```